# How to use function's name in across() when combining functions?

Tags: r, dplyr, across

When I try to use the `across()` function with many functions to be applied, as a result I get columns named as can be seen below:

```
iris %>% summarise(across(Petal.Length, .fns = c(mean, median, var, sd), .names = "{fn}_{col}")

  1_Petal.Length 2_Petal.Length 3_Petal.Length 4_Petal.Length
1          3.758           4.35       3.116278       1.765298
```

The columns' names are `1_Petal.Length, 2_Petal.Length` etc., but what I want to get are functions' names instead of the numbers, e.g. `mean_Petal.Length, median_Petal.Length` etc. just as when there's only one function in the `.fns` argument. I know I can name the functions with `.fns = c(mean=mean, median=median, var=var, sd=sd)`, but is there any easier way which I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lst` instead of `c` :

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% summarise(across(Petal.Length, 
                  .fns = lst(mean, median, var, sd), 
                  .names = "{fn}_{col}"))

#  mean_Petal.Length median_Petal.Length var_Petal.Length sd_Petal.Length
#1             3.758                4.35         3.116278        1.765298
```

`lst` creates a named arguments automatically without specifying them manually like `c(mean=mean...)`.